# How should I choose the right accuracy goal in Nintegrate?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am calculating a numerical integral, but I am very surprise about the result that I get when I choose a different accuracy goal

My integral is:

```
NIntegrate[
  (u/(u^2 + v^2))*r*x*Exp[-6.6*Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]]*Exp[-2.48*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]*
    ((1 - (2.2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]))^2)*BesselJ[0, u*r]*BesselJ[0, u*x]*Cos[v*z]*
      Cos[y*v]*(Cos[Pi*z/0.1]*Cos[Pi*y/0.1])^2, 
  {u, 0,Infinity}, {v, 0, Infinity}, {r, 0, Infinity}, {x, 0, Infinity}, 
  {z,0, 0.05}, {y, 0, 0.05}, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 4]
```

When I put a low accuracy goal (for example 4), I don't get warning messages and the result is

> ```
> 0.0000186452
> ```

but, when I put a higher accuracy goal, for example 8, I get warning messages and this result:

> ```
> 5.85387*10^-6
> ```
>
> NIntegrate::eincr: The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of the following: the working precision is insufficient for the specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. NIntegrate obtained 0.41556849973290244`and 1.9178217141492217`*^-6 for the integral and error estimates.

I am wondering about the difference in the results, and I would like to know in which result may I trust?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(109772)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109772); also related: [(1118249)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1118249)

Comment: I generally do not trust results obtained when I get `NIntegrate::eincr`. The error suggests that `NIntegrate` is still in the pre-convergent phase of the recursive refinement.  You can probably trust the first 4 decimal places (i.e. the zeros, where 4 = AG) of the first result -- that is, the true value is probably between `0.000018 ± 10^-4`.

Comment: I have tried other method of integration, MonteCarloMethod, but also the greatest accuracy that I can achieve without warning messages is 4, i got 0.0000202727. I need to have a higher accuracy at least 8...I have already tried to increase the precision, but nothing works!

Comment: fyi one of the integrals can be done analytically: `Integrate[integrand, {v, 0, Infinity},  Assumptions -> {u > 0, z > 0, y > 0}]`  You might get better results if you use that to reduce the dimension of the space for `NIntegrate`.  ( I made all the constants exact btw )