# Help needed to make NIntegrate Converge

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I have the following notebook (trying to caclulate the pull-in voltage of a structure):

```
phi1 = b1 Cos[1.03855 x1] - b1 Cosh[1.03855 x1] + a1 Sin[1.03855 x1] -
   a1 Sinh[1.03855 x1]

phi2 = b2 Cos[1.84683 x2] + d2 Cosh[1.84683 x2]

param = {b1 -> -0.255808, b2 -> 0.0340514, d2 -> 0.00305984, a1 -> 1, 
  c1 -> -1}

(*Numeric Constants*)
h = 2*10^-6;
wa = 10*10^-6;
la = 60*10^-6;
w = 100*10^-6;
l = 100*10^-6;
g = 1*10^-6;
e = 160*10^9;
epsilon0 = 8.85*10^-12;
sig0 = 0

i1 = wa*h^3/12;
i2 = w*h^3/12;
Area1 = h*wa;
Area2 = h*w;


θ = (Area2/Area1)^(1/4);
α = (i2/i1)^(1/4);
u = la/(l + la);
y = l/(l + la);


numericPhi1[x1_] = phi1 /. param
numericPhi2[x2_] = phi2 /. param

ph[x_] = Piecewise[{{numericPhi1[x], 
     0 <= x <= u}, {numericPhi2[1 - x], u < x <= 1}}];

ϕ[x_] := 
  Piecewise[{{ph[x], 0 <= x <= 1}, {ph[2 - x], 1 < x <= 2}}];
b[x_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{wa, 0 <= x <= u}, {w, u < x <= 1}, {w, 
    1 < x <= 1 + (1 - u)}, {wa, 1 + (1 - u) < x <= 2}}]
i[x_?NumericQ] := 
 Piecewise[{{i1, 0 <= x <= u}, {i2, u < x <= 1}, {i2, 
    1 < x <= 1 + (1 - u)}, {i1, 1 + (1 - u) < x <= 2}}]

nom[n_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(b[x] ϕ[x])/(g - n ϕ[x])^2, {x, 0, 2}]

denom[n_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(2 b[x] ϕ[x]^2)/(g - n ϕ[x])^3, {x, 0, 2}]
```

Now I try something simple:

```
nom[1.5]
```

If I do that I get the following warning:

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy
>   after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.00164274}. NIntegrate
>   obtained 1.0191585739576856`*^7 and 9.39610858946137`*^6 for the
>   integral and error estimates.

As you can see the error estimate is catastrophically huge `9.39610858946137*10^6`, hence I do not trust the result.

As pointed out in the comments by @AccidentalFourierTransform, it might be due to my numeric constants, since they vary over large magnitudes. However, I cannot change those constants as they are fixed by the physics of the problem.

**Any help would be very much appreciated !**

Comment: `ph[x], phi[x], ...`depend on a parameter u, which isn't defined! Perhaps that's the reason why the second errormessage occurs?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you very much ! I added u as a constant, but it did not change anything. :(

Comment: I just changed the definition ` ph[x_]:=... .The function b[x] isn't numeric , because of undefined parameters w,wa! That is the reason why  your first Integration ` nom[n]=...` cannot be evaluated numerically.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you ! I was a bit quick witch copy-pasting my code to stack exchange. Now I included all the constants.... but it still does not work. :(

Comment: You have constants that differ by dozens of orders of magnitude; numerical results will be catastrophically bad. Please, work in natural units, where all parameters are of order one.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform This is a good idea. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Should we have `t=x`?

Comment: @mikado Why ? What makes you think that ?

Comment: `nom[n], denom[n]`are complex valued,    is this intended?

Comment: What is the meaning of parameter t? No value is assigned, I think  that's the reason why the last integral `p=...`cannot be evaluated??

Comment: @UlrichNeumann `norm[n]`and `denom[n]` can be complex, yes, but the resulting  `n`should not be complex. Also, thanks a lot for spotting the missing `t` assignment. Please see the updated question.

Comment: Something is obviously wrong with those `Piecewise`, what the hell is the `{x, 0, 
    2}`?

Comment: @xzczd Uhm... that's how I thought that you need to define the piecwise function, to tell it that x goes from 0 to 2. Is that wrong ?

Comment: ……Please press **F1** and check the document of `Piecewise` carefully.

Comment: @xzczd I have changed the `Piecewise`function but unfortunately it still does not work.

Comment: @james Your actual code now works  (MMA 11.0.1) without error messages :`vPI=1.99883*10^-7` Is this the optimum you are looking for?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann It should actually be around 5, but it might be my mistake and not the code fault. However, when I execute it, it tells me that NIntegrate fails to converge, therefore, I don't know if I can trust the result for "n".

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I boiled down the question to the reveal the bottleneck. Please have a look at the updated code.

Comment: @xzczd  boiled down the question to the reveal the bottleneck. Please have a look at the updated code.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform  boiled down the question to the reveal the bottleneck. Please have a look at the updated code.

Comment: The two excellent answers ( @AccidentalFourierTransform,  @Michael E2) show, that the integral might only exist for `n<0.000026946` . Is this parameter range physically meaningful? If so, the question  seems to have found an answer!?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, I selected the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Some notes on debugging numerical solvers.***

Singularities can cause all sorts of trouble with numerical routines.  Sometimes it's not easy to tell whether your function has one if it has a complicated formula.  Having a denominator as the OP's `nom[]` does, certainly should suggest the possibility, and it should be one of the first things a user investigates.
Making a graph is a relatively cheap way to examine a function for potential singularities, at least for univariate or bivariate functions.
@AccidentalFourierTransform has already pointed out that indeed singularities are at the root of the trouble with `nom[1.5]`.  Aside from emphasizing the Make-A-Graph strategy, I want to show that there is a feasible domain for `n` and how to find it.

**Make A Graph**

The somewhat consistent syntax design of *Mathematica* makes this simple: Copy input (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-L on a Mac), change the command (`NIntegrate`) to `Plot`, nix the options.  In this case, we have to copy the code from `nom` and insert a value for `n`:

```
Plot[(b[x] ϕ[x])/(g - n ϕ[x])^2 /. n -> 1.5, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Well, we see part of the graph being cut off. So we have to extend the `PlotRange`:

```
Plot[(b[x] ϕ[x])/(g - n ϕ[x])^2 /. n -> 1.5, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The spikes at or near `x == 0, 2` might be vertical asymptotes (truncated by discrete sampling).  The graph suggests there might be a problem

**Analyzing the integrand**

The integrand is a complicated combination of `Piecewise` functions that stumps `Solve` and gives `NSolve` some difficulty.  One can get at the pieces in various ways.  [`PiecewiseExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html) will produce a single `Piecewise` function.  `Part` 2 of each element of `Part` 1 of a `Piecewise` function yields the intervals for each piece and reveals the singularities where the pieces join:

```
PiecewiseExpand[(b[x] ϕ[x])/(g - n ϕ[x])^2][[1, All, 2]]
(*  {3/8 < x <= 1, 1 < x < 13/8, 13/8 < x <= 2, x == 13/8, 0 <= x <= 3/8}  *)
```

Passing these points to the numerical routine normally helps, when the function is otherwise well-behaved.  For example, for feasible values of `n`, the following is faster than the OP's definition:

```
nom[n_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(b[x] ϕ[x])/(g - n ϕ[x])^2, {x, 0, 3/8, 1, 13/8, 2}];
```

We can get the expression for the denominator corresponding to the first singularity shown in the graph above using the second argument of `PiecewiseExpand`, which are assumptions to be applied in the expansion:

```
PiecewiseExpand[g - n ϕ[x], 0 < x < 3/8]
(*
  1/1000000 - n (-0.255808 Cos[1.03855 x] + 0.255808 Cosh[1.03855 x]
                   + Sin[1.03855 x] - Sinh[1.03855 x])
*)
```

This factor of the denominator is an analytic function and so has integer-order zeros. The denominator itself, being its square, has zeros of order 2 or higher (if it has any zero), which would not be integrable as @AccidentalFourierTransform has also pointed out.  Where the factor is zero then determines whether function is integrable over `{x, 0, 3/8}`.  It is similar for the other pieces.

**Solving for `n`**

The equation `g - n ϕ[x] == 0` is difficult to solve for `x` but easy for `n`:

```
npw = n /. First@Solve[g - n ϕ[x] == 0, n] // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can see how the singularity at `x` depends on `n` by plotting the inverse relation:

```
Plot[npw, {x, 0, 2}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {x, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The minimum value of `n` is at `x == 1`:

```
n0 = npw /. x -> 1
(*  0.000026946  *)
```

For values of `n` less than `n0`, the integral converges:

```
nom[0.9 n0]
nom[0]
nom[-1]
(*
  1.5136*10^8
  3.9056*10^6
  0.0344148
*)
```

Comment: Ah, really good analysis. I checked that there were singularities for any $n$ sufficiently large, but I didn't go to very small values (I think the minimal value I took was `n = 0.0001`). I jumped into conclusions too fast there, and you're right that for sufficiently small `n`, the singularities disappear. Nice!

Comment: I did get the value of `n0 = 0.000026` (cf. one of my comments below my answer), but my interpretation of that result was wrong: I realised that for that value the two singularities merge into one, but I thought that for smaller `n` they would separate again. Silly me, they disappear instead!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I must have missed the significance of the comment (or missed the comment entirely).  Thanks for the compliment.

Answer (score 7):

**Your integral doesn't exist**: the integrand has a non-integrable singularity in the integration region. This singularity is given by the solution of `g == n ϕ[x]`:

```
zero[n_] := FindRoot[g - n ϕ[x] == 0, {x, .002}][[1, 2]]
```

and the integrand diverges around this point, faster than $x^{-2}$:

```
With[{n = 1.5}, Plot[(g - n ϕ[x])^2/x^2, {x, .9 zero[n], 1.1 zero[n]}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-10^-8, 10^-8}}]]
```

[image]

(while the numerator of the integrand stays regular there).

This is the reason `NIntegrate` was not able to integrate your function. Your problem is ill-defined and has no solution, so **you probably made a conceptual mistake somewhere**.

(Actually, I now realise the integrand has *two* singularities, cf. the comment below; the integral is still ill-defined)

---

OP seems unconvinced the integral diverges. Let $x_1,x_2$ denote the two singularities, that is, the two solutions of `g == n ϕ[x]`. We can omit from the integral the intervals $[x_1-\epsilon,x_1+\epsilon]$ $[x_2-\epsilon,x_2+\epsilon]$ for some small $\epsilon>0$, thus rendering the integral well-defined:

```
zero1[n_] := FindRoot[g - n ϕ[x] == 0, {x, .002}][[1, 2]]
zero2[n_] := FindRoot[g - n ϕ[x] == 0, {x, 1.9}][[1, 2]]

nom[n_?NumericQ, ϵ_] := NIntegrate[(b[x] ϕ[x])/(g - n ϕ[x])^2, {x, 0, zero1[n] - ϵ}] + 
                        NIntegrate[(b[x] ϕ[x])/(g - n ϕ[x])^2, {x, zero1[n] + ϵ, zero2[n] - ϵ}] +
                        NIntegrate[(b[x] ϕ[x])/(g - n ϕ[x])^2, {x, zero2[n] + ϵ, 2}];

denom[n_?NumericQ, ϵ_] := NIntegrate[(2 b[x] ϕ[x]^2)/(g - n ϕ[x])^3, {x, 0, zero1[n] - ϵ}] + 
                          NIntegrate[(2 b[x] ϕ[x]^2)/(g - n ϕ[x])^3, {x, zero1[n] + ϵ, zero2[n] - ϵ}] + 
                          NIntegrate[(2 b[x] ϕ[x]^2)/(g - n ϕ[x])^3, {x, zero2[n] + ϵ, 2}];
```

With this, we note that the numerator diverges as $\epsilon^{-1}$ as $\epsilon\to0$:

```
Show[LogLogPlot[num[n,ϵ], {ϵ, .00005, .1}], Plot[-x - 11, {x, -10, 1}, PlotStyle -> Orange]]
```

[image]

and so does the denominator (demostration left to the reader).

So, again: **the integral doesn't exist**. Not even as a [Cauchy-principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value). (And even if it did, it would be hard to argue that a physical system requires that a regularisation in particular, which is non-unique and not really that special or natural).

Note: both the numerator and the denominator diverge as $\epsilon^{-1}$ as $\epsilon\to0$, so the quotient is well-defined in such a limit. But this regularisation does not seem to be physically justified to me, and I am almost positive OP made a mistake somewhere, so I don't want to encourage this approach.

Comment: Hmm... what if you change the `n`? It might exist for a specific `n`, the one I am searching for. Have you seen the answer, I gave ? When I approximate the functions phi1 and phi2 using a fit, it seems to work, but I am not getting the correct result.. So you might be wright. However, i am not getting an error either..

Comment: @james The integrand has a singularity for any $n>0$. For $n\to0^+$ the singularity is around $x\to0^+$, and for $n\to+\infty$ the singularity is around $x\to 2^-$. This behaviour stays the same even if you use the approximate phi1, phi2. The integral does not exist, for any `n`, and regardless of whether you use the exact function or the `Fit` one. Maybe you made an algebraic mistake somewhere? Or `n` should be negative?

Comment: In fact, it has a pair of singularities: one around $x\to0^+$, and one around $x\to 2^-$, for any $n$. As you decrease $n$, these two singularities get closer and they cross around $n=0.00002$.

Comment: How do you see that the integral does not exist for any n ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your updated answer and sorry to bother you, but I still don't quite understand it. To me it seems that you are finding a singularity for a specific `n` and not for all `n`in general. Please excuse me, if this might sound trivial to you, but I still need a bit of help to understand it. Thank you so much ! :)

Comment: @james No problem, I'm here to help. I chose `n = 1.5` for illustration purposes (and because this is the value for `n` you used in the OP). But the behaviour is qualitatively the same for any value of `n`: the singularities move around, but they are still there. You could try to prove that `g == n ϕ[x]` has two solutions in the interval $x\in [0,2]$ for any $n>0$. I don't have a formal proof, but it is easy to check this numerically. I invite you to do it yourself.