# Convergence of integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I'm trying to calculate analytically the integral below

$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} -\frac{2 \mathrm{e}^{k^2/2 + 5} k^2 (k^2 + 10)}{(\mathrm{e}^{k^2/2 + 5} - 1)^2} \mathrm{d}k
$$

I've already plotted it and I'm pretty sure this integral converges. However, it seems Mathematica doesn't give me an expression for it.

Any clues?
Thanks!

Comment: You haven't given an integral. You've only given a function.

Comment: There is no analytical antiderivative. Try numerical integration.  There is no analytical antiderivative even for $\frac{1}{e^{k^2}-1}$ never mind the  much more complicated integrand you show.

Comment: Thanks @Nasser!

Comment: It converges. `NIntegrate[f[k], {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` gives `0.440988`.

Comment: I modified the expression to an integral by guessing. Please check whether it expresses what you originally meant.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no analytical solution for the integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the function is cannot be analytically integrated, but it converges when you do numerical integration:

```
f[k_] := ((2 Exp[k^2/2 + 5] k^2  (k^2 + 10))/(Exp[k^2/2 + 5] - 1)^2)

NIntegrate[f[k], {k, -∞, ∞}]
```

which gives `0.440988`.

It is worth noticing that the (numerical) integral up to an unknown value $k_{max}$ can actually be well approximated (for $k>1$) by a sigmoid fit:

[image: ![enter image description here]

where the points are the result from the numerical integral, and the solid line is this fit:
$$ \frac{1}{2.26922 + \mathrm{e}^{2.36821(2.03168-x)}}. $$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. 
Now the integral converged for a range of parameters. However, for some parameters I obtain the following message:

NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in k near {k} = {5.31442*10^7}. NIntegrate obtained -4.89281*10^40+3.28288*10^28 I and 2.2012203052999983`*^40 for the integral and error estimates.

Do you know how could I fix it?

Comment: See this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109772/workingprecision-and-accuracygoal-for-using-with-nintegrate

Comment: Dear @SuperCiocia, I've read this question already. 
However, for my case, I can use WorkingPrecision->100 and AccuracyGoal-> Infinity that the problem still remains:

Comment: Then they might be as big numbers that Mathematica can store and handle.

Comment: It could be. But notice that I've renormalized the parameters of my integral and I'm still getting this error:

NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in k near {k} = {1.1053624000288337238*10^10}. NIntegrate obtained -11.988785460816550537 and 0.0037401556395867222549`20. for the integral and error estimates.

Comment: I never get that errror, can you include your exact code that is causing it?